# Debug error in frame$yval2[where, 1L + nclass + 1L:nclass, drop = FALSE]: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I'm using `rpart` library to build a regression tree, with the following code:

```
skillcraft <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00272/SkillCraft1_Dataset.csv", header = T, sep =",")

skillcraft$LeagueIndex <- factor(skillcraft$LeagueIndex)
skillcraft <- skillcraft[-1]
skillcraft$Age <- as.numeric(levels(skillcraft$Age))[skillcraft$Age]
skillcraft$TotalHours <- as.numeric(
  levels(skillcraft$TotalHours))[skillcraft$TotalHours]
skillcraft$HoursPerWeek <- as.numeric(
  levels(skillcraft$HoursPerWeek))[skillcraft$HoursPerWeek]

skillcraft <- skillcraft[complete.cases(skillcraft),]

library(caret)
set.seed(133)

skillcraft_sampling_vector <- createDataPartition(
  skillcraft$LeagueIndex, p = 0.8, list = F)

skillcraft_train <- skillcraft[skillcraft_sampling_vector,] 
skillcraft_test <- skillcraft[-skillcraft_sampling_vector,]


library(rpart)
regtree <- rpart(LeagueIndex ~., data = skillcraft_train)

regtree_predictions <- predict(regtree, skillcraft_test)
```

The last line of this code is throwing the error:

```
Error in frame$yval2[where, 1L + nclass + 1L:nclass, drop = FALSE] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

This doesn't seem very clear, but I've checked that both data frames (train and test) have the same structure and now I'm having trouble in finding a way to debug this code.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that the problem lies in the `LeagueIndex` factor. This variable was provided as ordinal data (from Bronze to Professional) and converted to a character factor `"1", "2", "3"`, etc. up to `"8"`.

It looks like in addition to your error with `rpart`, you get a warning when partitioning the data based on this factor:

> In createDataPartition(skillcraft$LeagueIndex, p = 0.8, list = F) :
>   Some classes have no records ( 8 ) and these will be ignored

Apparently there are no records with `LeagueIndex` of 8. This seems to come after you select for completed cases here:

```
skillcraft <- skillcraft[complete.cases(skillcraft),]
```

And all of the `LeagueIndex=8` cases are removed as these will have missing data for `Age`, `HoursPerWeek`, and `TotalHours` (coerced to `NA`) when converted via `as.numeric`.

```
skillcraft[which(skillcraft$LeagueIndex == 8), c("Age", "HoursPerWeek", "TotalHours")]
     Age HoursPerWeek TotalHours
3341   ?            ?          ?
3342   ?            ?          ?
3343   ?            ?          ?
...
```

Assuming you still wanted a factor, I believe if you get rid of the unused factor level this will work such as:

```
skillcraft$LeagueIndex <- droplevels(skillcraft$LeagueIndex)
```

before partitioning the data. (You could just do on the training set in this example, but you would want the same factor levels in your test and train sets.)

Comment: Hi @Ben that's right! I was converting LeagueIndex into factor. Without that line, the rest of the code runs smoothly. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Glad this was helpful. If you don’t need the factor that’s great.